# pass value to string.xml value that have a link inside it

Tags: android, string.xml

I have this value in string.xml file:

```
<string name="rights">Copyright © All Rights Reserved %1$d <b> <a href="http://www.example.com/">company name</a></b></string>
```

And I have applied this code that pass to the above text & set that text to the `TextView`

```
private void setupAppInfoRights() {

    int currentYear = Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.YEAR);
    String rights = String.format(new Locale("en"), getString(R.string.rights), currentYear);
    appInfoRights.setText(rights);
    appInfoRights.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());

}
```

When I remove the passed value everything goes fine & when the user click on the company name it takes him/her to the company website.

Please note that I have tried autoLink in xml when there is no value passed but it does not work as expected.

But, when I add the passed value & used the code above the company name has no underline & when the user clicks it , it will do nothing.

How to edit my above code to pass the current year & keep the link behavior normal?

**Note:** I have used `String.format` to display the current year as English number always despite the other locale numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think `SpannableStringBuilder` is what you are looking for.

```
  TextView linkTv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.link_tv);
  linkTv.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
  Spannable span = (Spannable) linkTv.getText();
  ClickableSpan clickableSpan = new ClickableSpan() {
     @Override
     public void onClick(View widget){
        //open the link
     }
  };
span.setSpan(clickableSpan, 0, span.length(), Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
 //for bold
span.setSpan(new android.text.style.StyleSpan(android.graphics.Typeface.BOLD), 0, span.length(), Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
```

If you want to make only certain part clickable then toggle the values of `0` and `span.length()` in `setSpan()`.

Answer (score 1):

When you have a string resource with both format arguments (like `%1$d`) and html markup, you have to use a multi-step process to create the styled `CharSequence`. This extra work is necessary because both `Resources.getString(int, Object...)` and `String.format(String, Object...)` can only return `String` instances, and not other `CharSequence` subclasses that are capable of holding styling information.

First, change your string resource to use html entities to escape the html tags:

```
<string name="rights">Copyright © All Rights Reserved %1$d &lt;b> &lt;a href="http://www.example.com/">company name&lt;/a>&lt;/b></string>
```

Next, obtain a `String` with the format arguments replaced with the actual values you desire:

```
String withHtmlMarkup = getString(R.string.rights, currentYear);
```

Finally, use `Html.fromHtml()` to parse the html markup:

```
CharSequence styled = Html.fromHtml(withHtmlMarkup);
```

Then you can set this `styled` text to your TextView as normal:

```
appInfoRights.setText(styled);
appInfoRights.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
```

Developer guide: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource#FormattingAndStyling

> Normally, this doesn't work because the `format(String, Object...)` and `getString(int, Object...)` methods strip all the style information from the string. The work-around to this is to write the HTML tags with escaped entities, which are then recovered with `fromHtml(String)`, after the formatting takes place.